# How to hide a button until a specific div is not shown in my page using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and even more in jQuery and I have the following problem.

In a JSP page that use Struts 2 tag library (but I think that this is not important) I have this form:

```
<s:form>
    <sj:div id="resultEvents" href="%{loadFolderTechId}"
            formIds="treeForm"
            class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
            loadingText=" "
            onBeforeTopics="before"
            onCompleteTopics="complete"
            deferredLoading="true"
            reloadTopics="reloadEvents">
      </sj:div>

      <s:submit action="projectCreationAction"/>
</s:form>
```

The  tag is the same thing that a classic html form (it is a Struts 2 UI tag that wrap a classic html form).

The inner  tag is like an HTML div with some AJAX behavior (it is shown only if a specific event is triggered) and it contains the form input tag.

In the specific case in the page there is (not show in the snippet) a JsTree showing a tree and when the user click on a node of this tree the content of this form is shown (the  is shown).

Ok, under this , there is the  that show a button to submit the form.

At this time this button is always shown, even when it is not shown the content of the previous .

So what I have to do is to make hidden the  button when the content of the  is not shown.

When the  is shown it renders the following HTML code inside my page:

```
<div id="resultEvents" class="class java.util.HashMap">
    <div id="">Creazione Progetto</div>
    <br>
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        ..............................................
        ..............................................
        ..............................................
    </table>
</div>
```

So I am thinking that maybe I code using JavaScript or jQuery to hidden my  until the div **id="resultEvents"** is not rendered on my page.

Is it a correct use of AJAX or exist some better solution to do it? If it is a good solution how can I implement it?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a link to the page? Would make it easier to understand the problem.. If I understand it correctly: you want to make a button visible (that is already present in the DOM, but hidden). For that you don't need to contact the server (like you would with Ajax). To hide the button initially use css. Then use an eventhandler to toggle the visible state of the button as desired.

Comment: I can't give you a link because the page is not online. Yes you understand my problem. I want that the button is not hidden if the div having id=resultEvents is showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you can try to put `<script>` tag in your div with id `resultEvents`

This will look like the following:

```
   <s:form>
<sj:div id="resultEvents" href="%{loadFolderTechId}"
        formIds="treeForm"
        class="result ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
        loadingText=" "
        onBeforeTopics="before"
        onCompleteTopics="complete"
        deferredLoading="true"
        reloadTopics="reloadEvents">
<script type = 'text/javascript' >$('.yourButtonClassName').show()</script>

  </sj:div>


  <s:submit style='display:none' class='yourButtonClassName' action="projectCreationAction"/>
```

You should give a className to your button (for example `yourButtonClassName`)
And hide it by default: add style='display:none'

Let me know if it helps=)

Comment: he prop. wants the button to be hidden when the div is removed from DOM or hidden though..

Comment: Yes, it help. I have adatped it to my specific case and it solved, tnx :-)